# String compare with multiple wildcards

Tags: vba, excel

I want to compare 2 set of strings, 2 file names, one from an Excel range and the other from a SharePoint site (not sure if this matters). While looking at the strings they look similar, the code does not deem it so. All substrings, let's say, can vary. The only constants are "_MONTHLY DATA" and the extension ".xlsx" . Any ideas on how to solve this ?

Example

```
 If "2018_01_MONTHLY DATA_TOTAL_EUROPE_Germany_CompanyName Deutschland.xlsx" _ 
Like "2018_01_MONTHLY DATA*Europe_Germany*.xlsx" Then
    MsgBox "It works"
Else
    Msgbox "It doesn't work"
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example to work you'll just need:

```
If "2018_01_MONTHLY DATA_TOTAL_EUROPE_Germany_CompanyName Deutschland.xlsx" _ 
Like "2018_01_MONTHLY DATA*EUROPE_Germany*.xlsx" Then
    MsgBox "It works"
Else
    Msgbox "It doesn't work"
End If
```

And if you want to make it case insensitive use `Option Compare Text`:

```
Option Compare Text
Sub so_question()

If "2018_01_MONTHLY DATA_TOTAL_EUROPE_Germany_CompanyName Deutschland.xlsx" Like "2018_01_MONTHLY DATA*Europe_Germany*.xlsx" Then
    MsgBox "It works"
Else
    MsgBox "It doesn't work"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: So it's case sensitive... didn't think of that one to be honest, thanks!